# React Native parsing response JSON into a flatlist

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, react-native, rest

I am trying to parse the response JSON from the following json data:

```
{
  "location_id": 73,
  "location_name": "Aunt Mary's Great Coffee Shop",
  "location_town": "London",
  "latitude": 74.567,
  "longitude": 102.435,
  "photo_path": "http://cdn.coffida.com/images/78346822.jpg",
  "avg_overall_rating": 4.5,
  "avg_price_rating": 4.3,
  "avg_quality_rating": 4,
  "avg_clenliness_rating": 3.8,
  "location_reviews": [
    {
      "review_id": 643,
      "overall_rating": 4,
      "price_rating": 2,
      "quality_rating": 3,
      "clenliness_rating": 5,
      "review_body": "Great coffee, but the bathrooms stank!",
      "likes": 4654
    }
  ]
}
```

i am trying to parse the data fromt the location_ reviews array object. i am successfully recieving the data as i have checked in a console.log

i have also successfully recieved and printed the location name and id onto the screen

```
/* eslint-disable curly */
/* eslint-disable prettier/prettier */
/* eslint-disable react-native/no-inline-styles */
/* eslint-disable semi */
/* eslint-disable prettier/prettier */
    import React, {Component} from 'react';
    import {View, Text, ToastAndroid, FlatList, TouchableOpacity, StyleSheet} from 'react-native';

    class Location extends Component {
       constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
          locations: [],
          isLoading: true,
        };
      }

      getData = async () => {

        let loc_id = this.props.route.params.location_id;

        return await fetch(`http://10.0.2.2:3333/api/1.0.0/location/${loc_id}`, {
            method: 'get',
            'headers': {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
              },
            })
        .then((response) => {
              if (response.status === 200) {
                return response.json();
              } else if (response.status === 404) {
                ToastAndroid.show('Unable to locate location', ToastAndroid.SHORT);
              } else {
                throw 'something went wrong';
              }
            })
        .then((responseJson) => {

                const review = responseJson.location_reviews[0]
                console.log(review);

                this.setState({
                    locations: responseJson,
                    isLoading: false,
                  });

            })
        .catch((error) => {
              ToastAndroid.show(error.toString(), ToastAndroid.SHORT);
            });
      }

      renderItem = ({item, index}) => {
        let { locations } = item;

        if (!locations[0]) return null;
        let details = locations[0]

        return (
        <View>
            <View>
                <Text>{details.review_body}</Text>
                <Text>{details.review_id}</Text>
           </View>
        </View>
        );
      }

      keyExtractor = (item, index) => {
        return index.toString();
      }

      render() {
          return (
            <View style={styles.space}>
                  <TouchableOpacity
                  style={styles.space}
                    onPress = {() => this.getData()}
                  >
                          <View>
                              <Text>get data</Text>
                              <Text>Location id: {this.props.route.params.location_id}</Text>
                          </View>
                  </TouchableOpacity>

                  <View>
                    <Text style={styles.space}>{this.state.locations.location_name}</Text>
                    <Text style={styles.space}>{this.state.locations.location_town}</Text>
                  </View>

                  <View style={{flex: 1}}>
                      <FlatList
                        data={this.state.dataSource}
                        keyExtractor={this.keyExtractor}
                        renderItem={this.renderItem}
                      />
                  </View>

            </View>
              );
        }


   }

   const styles = StyleSheet.create({

    space: {
      margin: 20,
      padding: 20,
    },

   });

    export default Location;
```

however i am completely stuck on how the access the array of location review data(review_id, review_body etc.)

any ideas would be appreciated

Comment: i have created a snack for the code to be seen more clearly https://snack.expo.io/lAInpgHzH

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that the json_data you have above is an object, and `FlatList` must receive an array (it then calls `renderItem` with each item in that array, and displays this list of items).

There are a few changes you should make (I'm assuming that you want the `FlatList` to display a list of items from the `location_reviews` array):

1. In your constructor, the location field should be an object, and it is initially `null`:

```
this.state = {
  location: null,
}
```

2. In your render method, first check `this.state.location` exists and render nothing or a loading screen if it does not:

```
render() {
  const { location } = this.state;

  if (location === null) return null;
  ...
}
```

3. In your render method, pass `this.state.location.location_reviews` to your `FlatList`:

```
const { location } = this.state;

<FlatList
  data={location.location_reviews}
  ...
/>
```

4. Finally, adjust your `renderItem` method:

```
renderItem = ({item, index}) => {
  return (
    <View>
        <Text>{item.review_body}</Text>
        <Text>{item.review_id}</Text>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Note: I have not tested this as the snack does not work. You might need to adjust a few more things (ie. I changed this.state.locations -> this.state.location, etc.)

Comment: thankyou i managed to get the flatlist to render using a slightly different method but your way also works thankyou

Answer (score 0):

i managed to get the flatlist to compile using the following

```
  render() {
    if (this.state.isLoading) {
      return (
        <View>
          <Text>loading...</Text>
        </View>
      )
    } else return (
                  <View>
                      <Text>Name: {this.state.locations.location_name}</Text>
                      <FlatList
                        data={this.state.locations.location_reviews}
                        renderItem={({item}) => (
                          <View>
                              <Text>review id: {parseInt(item.review_id)}</Text>
                              <Text>body: {item.review_body}</Text>
                              <Text>overall rating: {parseInt(item.overall_rating)}</Text>
                              <Text>price rating: {parseInt(item.price_rating)}</Text>
                              <Text>quality rating: {parseInt(item.quality_rating)}</Text>
                              <Text>cleanliness rating: {parseInt(item.clenliness_rating)}</Text>
                          </View>
                        )}
                        keyExtractor={(item) => item.review_id.toString()}
                      />
                  </View>
          );
    }
```